# We are trying to automate installation of cloudera using ansible, but we are facing errors

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

We are beginners to ansible. When we are trying to run install-cloudera-manager.yml we are facing below errors

```
TASK [install CM server] *******************************************************
failed: [************cloudapp.net] (item=cloudera-manager-daemons) => {"failed": true, "item": "cloudera-manager-daemons", "msg": "No package matching '$item' is available"}
failed: [***********cloudapp.net] (item=cloudera-manager-server-db) => {"failed": true, "item": "cloudera-manager-server-db", "msg": "No package matching '$item' is available"}
failed: [***********.cloudapp.net] (item=cloudera-manager-server) => {"failed": true, "item": "cloudera-manager-server", "msg": "No package matching '$item' is available"}
```

we are referring scripts from below url:
https://github.com/ymc-geko/ansible-cdh-cluster  please help

Answer (score 0):

Failing task is:

```
  - name: install CM server
    action: apt pkg=$item state=latest
    with_items:
    - cloudera-manager-daemons
    - cloudera-manager-server-db
    - cloudera-manager-server
```

It uses early-Ansible dollar-sign variables. It is unsupported for years...

Change it to `apt pkg={{item}} state=latest` and try again.

Project that you reference was last updated in 2013, current Ansible version has many changes since that time. Keep this in mind.

Comment: The above error got resolved, but we got some new errors after changing that.

failed: [**.cloudapp.net] (item=cloudera-manager-daemons) => {"failed": true, "item": "cloudera-manager-daemons", "module_stderr": "Shared connection to ***.cloudapp.net closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "\r\nTraceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_9QiPvG/ansible_module_apt.py\", line 909, in <module>\r\n    main()\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_9QiPvG/ansible_module_apt.py\", line 855, in main\r\n    for package in packages:\r\nTypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE"}